# Can you reference a 'selected' cell in a matrix to generate a subreport in SSRS 2012?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So I know you can nest subreports in cells but what if I have a lot of data and I want to populate a subreport Dynamically.  Can you do that in SSRS that anyone knows of?

I typically drill down to a subreport but could you instead have a hidden variable or other value be captured or else a select reference know to a cell and have that be generated?

I have looked into concepts of Me.Value and ReportItems![ItemName].Value but they relate to a static position, not something that is an active cell chosen by your mouse.  Does anyone know if this is a limitation of the RDL language or is it possible?  In the simplest example I could do say I have a dataset with just one field 'Name' and it has two values 'Brett' and 'Sean'.  I create a table and set only one column with a header.  I create a textbox with an expression outside of that table as it's own element in the report body(to recreate what I would want to pass to a subreport).  I am hoping to capture a reference to what was in the table element selected.

Can I somehow have the report know that I clicked on the cell in the table and generate an event that fires off the value?  Or is the language not able to build references as such?  I was curious as I was not sure so I thought I would ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer is not really, because the report and the underlying data that's generated is static, and there's no event framework for generating more data - just altering the display of the existing data (expand/collapse, sort, etc.) (So in theory you could have the visibility of your textboxes be interactive based on clicking the textboxes, and then set the visibility of various data rows in some "master report" to be equal to the textboxes' visibility, so they "hide" and "show" as the user clicks the different textboxes. But then you'd have to have a "Reset all visibility" button, and a master report, and a lot of code-behind to figure out your subreport visibility rows ... sounds like a maintenance nightmare!)

Obviously your best option would be to build an ASP.NET web app with a Report Viewer Control. Then you get all the goodness of jQuery and server-side requests to handle passing parameters back from the client to the server, generate your subreport, return it (preferably as an ATOM data feed), parse it, and then inject it into the DOM how you want users to see it.

Some people have managed to [inject jQuery into the SSRS Report Manager headers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/74f90e77-143f-43e1-abc5-0cf00b764f18/) and so if you're really adventurous, you can try to recreate that same experience above within Report Manager, but it sounds like a hassle.

Comment: So from what I have read and looked for on the internet I can neither confirm nor deny this is the case.  I award you the answer but since it really does not help me I can't give you any up votes.  Hopefully there will be more functionality in the next version.  2012 I have yet to see any real difference over 2008 R2.

Comment: That's fine : ) If you're looking for some dynamic UX, you're much better of with a web application instead of something static like SSRS anyway. Maybe PowerView? Haven't messed much with it.

Comment: I was actually looking at HighCharts, http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail,  as they seem to be able to do a lot more dynamic stuff.  It would be java script based though and I am not certain yet of what I want for a front end.  I have been looking at all kinds of things.  I like SSRS a lot but I also know it has a lot of limitations with things as well.  Hover over features and events that are multi layered are really lacking in it from what I have seen.  I will still continue to use it as it can be very powerful for what it can do though.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you are looking for the feature in SSRS which is actions.
You can define an action when a cell is clicked which gives you various options of actions.

For that click on the cell, goto TextBox Properties, choose the action as goto report and add the parameters you want to pass.

In this example I have Report1 , for which when I click on the JobCandidate Cell, I navigate to Report2, along with that I pass a parameter which is the JobCandidate ID used by Report 2 parameter Param1 in Report2.
The value passed to Param1 is essentially the cell value, in this case Fields!JobCandidateId.Value
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not what I was looking for as I understand the actions property already.  I am looking for an object like a table that updates when a reference is clicked in another object table.  In my example if I clicked the column for 'Brett' it would populate a field with that value or else if I clicked 'Sean' it would change the value to Sean.  This is pretty dynamic so I was not sure if it is possible.  The limitation of the 'Go to report' is you go out of scope and step outside the current report object you are in.  I don't want that.